# jquery filereader: getting binary data instead of data URL

Tags: jquery, filereader

I am writing a jQuery code to upload image files and display thumbnails. I have this script which works fine for a single file.

```
        reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onload = (function (tFile) {
            return function (evt) {
                holder.innerHTML = '<img class="draggable" src="' + event.target.result + '" />';
            };
        }(file));
        reader.readAsDataURL(file);
```

I modified this script to support multiple image uploads as below. But I get only binary data in the src attribute and image is not displayed.

```
        reader = new FileReader();
        function readFile(index) {
        if( index >= files.length ) return;

        var file = files[index];
        reader.onload = (function(e) {  
            return function (evt) {
            $("#holder").append('<img class="thumbnail" width="150px" height="150px" "src="' + event.target.result + '" />');

            };

            readFile(index+1)
        }(file));
        reader.readAsDataURL(file);
    }
    readFile(0);
```

I am new to FileReader concept. Can someone please point out whats wrong with the above code.

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 0):

Well not exactly answer to your question, but won't following be better way to create and init `FileReader`:

```
reader = new FileReader();

reader.onload = function(e) {
    $("#holder").append('<img class="thumbnail" width="150px"' 
        + 'height="150px" "src="' + e.target.result + '" />');
};

$.each(files,function(i,file){
    reader.readAsDataURL(file);
});
```

Hope answer by Musa helped you. Following works but is bit different approach. It uses **[FileReaderJS](http://bgrins.github.io/filereader.js/)** plugin. This is a wrapper around **FileReader** and provides easy to use functionality.

You can specify `input` and `drop zone` and setup options for init.

```
var $tgt, options = {
        dragClass: "drag-here",
        accept: "image/*",
        readAsMap: {},
        readAsDefault: 'DataURL',
        on: {
            load: function(e, file) {
                var im = $("<img/>")
                    .attr("src", e.target.result)
                    .addClass('thm-img'),
                    dw = $("<div/>").addClass("col-sm-3"),
                    d = $("<div/>").addClass("thumbnail");
                d.append(im)
                dw.append(d)
                $tgt.append(dw);
            },
            error: function(e, file) {
                $("#log-start").append($("<div/>")
                    .addClass("text-error")
                    .text(e.target.error.code)
                );
            }
        }
    };

$(function() {
    $tgt = $("#holder"); //div where to show previews

    $("#selectFile, div.drag-backdrop").fileReaderJS(options);
});
```

Following is working [Plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/bTxUmg?p=preview) demonstrating it.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I used your script. It displays only first image. Then it returns this error: Failed to execute 'readAsDataURL' on 'FileReader': The object is already busy reading Blobs.

Comment: Tried to implement this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24843508/filereader-error-the-object-is-already-busy-reading-blobs. But couldn't get it working.

Comment: I'm trying to write test code and will update answer if got something right.

Comment: Will you check new option?

Comment: Thanks for your time and effort. I used Musa's code and altered it to get it working. here is the working demo: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/VYwgYo. I tested your code in Plunk demo. It was not displaying thumbnails.

Answer (score 0):

A simple way to do it would be to load one, when its finished, load another, when that one's finished load another etc...

```
    reader = new FileReader();
    function readFile(index) {
        if( index >= files.length ) return;

        var file = files[index];
        reader.onload = function (evt) {
            $("#holder").append('<img class="thumbnail" width="150px" height="150px" "src="' + evt.target.result + '" />');
            readFile(index+1);
        };

        reader.readAsDataURL(file);
    }
    readFile(0);
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. But this solution was giving "Failed to execute 'readAsDataURL' on 'FileReader': The object is already busy reading Blobs" error and it was displaying the first image multiple times(because of readFile(0);). I modified your code and got it working. Here is the demo: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/VYwgYo.